# Comptability support

Tags: accounting

New here, trying to know more about CiviCRM !

1. Is CiviCRM (and/or its extension)providing any support in terms of **accounting** for NGOs ?
2. If we already have a website on **wix**, is it possible to integrate some features (online donations, memberships forms, newsletter suscribers database etc..) ?

   3. Is there a technical assistance (phone, email..) in the CiviCore Team available to respond to urgent matters, bugs, etc if need be ?

Thanks a lot for your precious help and comment !

Inès

Answer (score 2):

Trying to provide some answers:

1. Depends on what you mean by support for accounting, can you define that in a little more detail? CiviCRM can store contributions, event fees and membership fees and will store them with a specific financial type, linked to a financial account. For each of those contributions, event fees and member dues it will also generate financial transactions. You can assign those transactions to an accounting batch, which you will be able to download in CSV format (or IIF out of the top of my head) which you can then import in your financial system.
2. It is certainly possible to communicate with CiviCRM from any type
   of website using the API. So it will also be possible to create
   online donations etc. If you want to use some of the standard
   generated pages, you can probably do some by including the page in
   your Wix website. But it will require some consideration about what
   you want exactly, what the alternatives are and what the pros and
   cons of each alternative are. Some of the NGO's I work with want
   their public website and CiviCRM on separate servers for
   security/privacy considerations (and it makes sense IMO). But the
   consequence is that some of the nice and easy-to-use form modules
   that allow easy access to CiviCRM data need some adaptation.
3. There is certainly technical assistance from a CiviCRM partner in
   your region. There is as far as I know no Core Team technical
   assistance because that does not fit into our community model. It
   would mean having a big Core Team, while we have a small one
   focusing on the core product and a large group of partners focusing
   on supporting partners. So check where your nearest partner is
   [here](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors). All of the contributors and partners you will find on
   this list are active in the community and know their stuff when it
   comes to CiviCRM. You can obviously also try to find another
   organization that is not on the list that says they know about
   CiviCRM, but you run a little more risk then with the listed
   contributors and partners.